# Make slider value appear in NoUISlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, rangeslider, nouislider

I'm new to NoUISlider and I've managed get the slider to work. However, the slider value is not visible or appears to work.

I'm new to jQuery as well, so I'm not sure why the slider value code isn't working.

The website I'm editing is right here: [Experian Map](http://planet.nu/dev/test/map.html)

Here's my code:

```js
<script>
$(function(){

  $('#slider-range').noUiSlider({

    range: {
        'min': 0,
        '10%': 10,
        '20%': 20,
        '30%': 30,

        '50%': 50,
        '60%': 60,
        '70%': 70,

        '90%': 90,
        'max': 100
    },
    snap: true,
    start: [20]
 });
});
    </script>

<script>
  $(function(){
 $('#slider-range').Link('lower').to($('#slider-range-value'));
</script>
```

```css
.example-val{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}

.example-val:before {
    content: "Value: ";
    font: 700 12px Arial;
 }   

 #slider-range-value{
   color: #FFF;
 }
```

```html
     <div id="slider-range"></div><span id="slider-range-value" class="example-val"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is OK, but you've got several syntax errors. Opening your browser console (press F12) would help.

Fixed code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slider-range').noUiSlider({
        range: {
            ...
        },
        snap: true,
        start: [20]
    });

    $('#slider-range').Link('lower').to($('#slider-range-value'));
}); // << was missing
```